# Dynatree extra attribute

Tags: php, jquery, dynatree

I'm using dynatree and generating my dynatree out of json.
Is it possible that I've an extra attribute (data_key) in my fields so I can work with the dynatree with my PHP as well? I want a hover effect on the icons from the dynatree, the pop-up that is coming up, needs to have some data of the "hovered" node.

Somebody an answer?

Comment: How are you generating the tree from the json?

Comment: Putting everything in jsonItems and that in my JsonData[] and json_encode it. I'm creating the tree on the "initAjax" of the dynatree. But in the php (where I'm making the jsonItems), I need also an data-key or something in the JsonItems. I can make classes on each node (JsonItem['addClass']), but not something like a data-key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom properties that you add to the JSON child array will be copied to node.data.
So if you pass `[{"title": "node 1", "myAttr": "foo"}, ...]` you can accesss it like `node.data.myAttr`.